# using sed to print next line after match

Tags: macos, mac, bash, sed

I came across various examples on printing next line after a match, that use awk and sed. 
I'm using it in my code and it works fine. Now I want to use a variable instead of a hardcoded value for the pattern match. The search pattern string includes forward slashes "/". How do I use a variable that has "/" in it and use it to print the next line after the match? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
 var="/somePath/to/my/home"  
 val=`echo -e "$someStr" | sed -n ':$var:{n;p;}'`
```

In this case, val is always blank.  I'm using using ":" as the delimiter instead of "/". I'm on a Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `sed` command as follows:

```
sed -n "\:$var: {n;p;}"
```

Two points:

1. The best you could have hoped for with your version is to search for “`$var`”. To search for “`/somePath/to/my/home`”, you must replace your single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`) to allow “`$var`” to be replaced by “`/somePath/to/my/home`”.
2. In `sed`, a delimited regular expression can look like

> `/`     *regular_expression*     `/`

or

> `\`*other_delimiter*   *regular_expression*   *other_delimiter(repeated)*

so you need the `\` before the `:`.

Answer (score 1):

While setting the variable "var", escape the backslashes:

```
var="\/somePath\/to\/my\/home"
sed -n "/$var/{n;p;}" file
```